# Cleaning existing images in PersonPicture WinRT/C++

Tags: c++-winrt, xaml-islands

In my application, there are two functions to add and clean image in `PersonPicture`. However, I don't know of a way to clean up the image that has been added in the `PersonPicture`. **So, how to clean the image that has been added in the `PersonPicture`?**

Example of the code.

```
// Xaml file
<PersonPicture x:Name="UserProfile"/>

// Cpp file
void MyPage::AddImage(hstring const& path)
{
    Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging::BitmapImage bitmap{ Windows::Foundation::Uri(path) };
    UserProfile().ProfilePicture(bitmap);
}

void MyPage::ClearImage()
{
    // Clean up the image that has been added in PersonPicture.
    // However,
    // How to do that here?
}
```

Comment: Pretty difficult to tell, what you are trying to accomplish and where you're failing. You're talking about `PersonPicture`, but then there is no `PersonPicture` anywhere.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.